# Weird behavior swapping two array elements while indexing by elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7

I ran into a weird behavior trying to swap elements of an array.

#### Initial State

```py
i = 1
nums = [0, 1]
```

#### What didn't worked

```py
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
print(nums) # [0, 1]
```

#### What worked

```py
nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1]
print(nums) # [1, 0]
```

I believed both expressions should have had the same outcome as the right-side of assignment is evaluated first.

Tested on Python 2.7.16 and Python 3.7.6 on macOS Catalina, 10.15.4.

Note: `nums[1], nums[0] = nums[0], nums[1]` and `nums[0], nums[1] = nums[1], nums[0]` work just as expected.

Comment: Why don't you just swap like this? 'nums[i], nums[i-1] = nums[i-1], nums[i]'

Comment: @Mace This is just an example. The elements to be swapped might be anywhere in the array. I was using this as part of cycle sorting.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understand Python swapping: why is a, b = b, a not always equivalent to b, a = a, b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68152730/understand-python-swapping-why-is-a-b-b-a-not-always-equivalent-to-b-a-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the arguments on the left hand side of the assignment, are still evaluated left-to-right. Let's break down the non-working example:

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[nums[i]-1], nums[i]
```

becomes

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = nums[0], nums[1]
```

becomes

```
nums[i], nums[nums[i]-1] = 0, 1
```

now the left hand side is evaluated, but `nums[i]` is evaluated first. This makes `nums[1]` into `0`.

Now if we evaluate `nums[nums[i] - 1]`, we see that this evaluates to `nums[0 - 1]`, which is `nums[-1]`, which is `nums[1]`.

So this entire expression does nothing. It simply sets `nums[1]` to `0`, and then back to `1`.